Does the case that a non-base-10 value is written in matter? If so, which should be chosen?
Query
As this question on GitHub summarises, when writing integers in higher positive bases (like 36 or 16) whether to write them in upper or lower case doesn't appear to be well documented.
Mathematically, does it matter? If so or not, might I know why? If not, my sole assumption is because theoretically any character set can be chosen to represent the numbers.
Irrespective, if a standard exists, I'll be glad to have it cited so that I can conform to it.
Examples
I've read cambiaresearch.com/articles/241022/intro-to-number-bases-and-the-cambia.basen-package#sec-35KAUHSNAVJ6PKJ8CP5EL7FHH, which states:

The Cambia.BaseN library will not equate upper and lower case letters.
This is because once you get to bases above 36 you have both upper and lower case letters in your alphabet. In base-62 for example A really is distinct from a.

This appears to be somewhat opinionated, for I would expect that bases beneath a specific value would not be affected by this, considering that they solely utilize one character set.
Additionally, this example is rather specific to a computer-based implementation.
Meta

(Lack of) Duplicates

https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=numerical+base+upper+or+lower+case and
https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=upper+case+base

both returned 0 relevant results (at +2024-10-26T20:38:14+01:00).

Tags
I really struggled to ascertain which to choose, hence merely article-writing, which is tangentially related at best. I'm no mathematician.



As $32=2^5$ is more likely to be met than for example $36$,  have a look at the "standard" ways to write base-32 digits here

For base $~36,~$ since $~36 = 10 + 26,~$ I would extend the pattern found in the base $~16~$ pattern of expressing each digit as some element in $~{ ~0,1,\cdots,9,A,B,\cdots,F ~}.~$  That is, for base $~36,~$ I would express each digit as some element in $~{ ~0,1,\cdots,9,A,B,\cdots,Z ~}.$  However, as other responses have indicated, since there is no generally accepted convention for (for example) base $~36,~$ I would very clearly document whatever convention that you arbitrarily adopt, before using that convention.

@JeanMarie, thanks for the recommendation! Indeed, Wikipedia states that it is standard to utilize solely upper-case, so I shall conform to that.

This isn't really a mathematical question. In computing, it is standard to use the letters "abcdef" or "ABCDEF" to represent the digits with values from $10$ to $15$ when working in base $16$ (hexadecimal). If you go above base $16$, you are on your own and it is down to you to state what conventions you are using.
